# fork and waitpid in C

Tags: c, linux, fork, waitpid

I have this piece of code, maybe I'm missing something:

```
const int NPROCESSES = 32;   
pid_t pids[128];

for (int i = 0; i < NPROCESSES;i ++) {
   pids[i] = fork();
   if (!pids[i]) {  
       /*... other code ...*/
       exit(0);
   }
}

for (int i = 0; i < NPROCESSES; i++)
    waitpid(pids[i], 0, 0);
```

The program should launch 32 processes and wait until all processes are terminated. But sometimes the program get blocked with child zombie processes.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: One possibility is that you can't create as many as 32 processes. You don't error check `waitpid()` — you should. Note that if `fork()` fails, the recorded 'pid' is `-1`, and when you do `waitpid(-1, 0, 0)`, you will wait for any child that's exited, which would mean that there won't be a corpse for one of the other pids that you plan to wait for. However, `waitpid()` won't block when you request the status info for a pid that has already been collected, so this isn't a complete diagnosis. You should, however, have lots more diagnostic printing and you should fanatically check system calls.

Answer (score 5):

Using:

```
waitpid(pids[i], 0, 0);
```

you specify an exact order in which the parent will reap its children: it will be the same order as they were created.

As a result, if one of the children blocks or delays for any reason, and some other child which was created later has already finished (and called `exit()`), the latter will remain in a zombie state, until the parent reaps the former child first.

So if, for example, the process created in the first iteration of the loop needs 1min to complete and the rest 31 processes are completed in 1sec, you're be able to observe 31 zombie processes waiting to be reaped by their parent, who (the parent) will wait to reap that one delayed process first.

To change this behavior, the parent can use:

```
waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
```

instead. A value equal to `-1` in the first argument of `waitpid()` means it will reap any of the child processes, quoting from [`man 2 waitpid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html):

> The value of `pid` can be:
>
> `< -1`
>
> meaning wait for any child process whose process group ID is equal to
>   the absolute value of pid.
>
> **`-1`**
>
> **meaning wait for any child process.**
>
> `0`
>
> meaning wait for any child process whose process group ID is equal to
>   that of the calling process.
>
> `> 0`
>
> meaning wait for the child whose process ID is equal to the value of
>   pid.

Alternatively, you can just use:

```
wait(NULL);
```

which is the same as `waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)`.